# Default values automatically save in database when plugin will be activated

Tags: database, wordpress

I have used a WordPress Settings API PHP Class framework, that found  here http://tareq.wedevs.com/2012/06/wordpress-settings-api-php-class/, to create my first plugin setting page.

Everything is working fine except default option values are not saving in database until I hit "Save" going to setting page. But I would like this to be saved automatically when someone activate the plugin.

I tried using `register_activation_hook()` but failed. I am not sure how to use that framework with `register_activation_hook()`. You can check the codes going to the link I mentioned above. I am about to finish my first plugin but stuck on this.

Comment: Hi Rahil, Sorry I didn't get you. How should the question be formatted?

Comment: Show us the code you tried so far. Don't just link to external sources atleast add some relevant part of it (Link only sources later may not be found).